# Manera correcta de implementar un ProgressDialog cuando se crea y envía un PDF a un correo

Tags: java, android-studio, itext

Buenos días espero que la pregunta este bien redactada pero no sabia de que otra manera preguntar, resulta que tengo un inconveniente al momento de implementar un progressDialog cuando realizo 2 acciones esas dos acciones son crear un PDF y posteriormente enviarlo hacia un correo, eso ya lo hago de manera correcta el problema radica cuando realizo la acción, debido a que al darle al botón enviar entra a 2 métodos la aplicación se congela unos segundos hasta que el proceso se completa por ende yo quise implementar un progressDialog mientras esas peticiones se están realizando, a continuación explicare de la mejor manera mi código:

Como primer punto cabe recalcar que tengo 2 métodos uno llamado "crearPDF" y el otro llamado "enviarPDF" como lo había mencionado el primer método crea un PDF en una ruta especificada de el dispositivo Android y el segundo método envía ese PDF creado hacia un correo especificado, sin mas explico parte de la lógica que e implementado.

crearPDF

```
public void crearPDF() throws IOException, DocumentException {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    Font fuente = new Font();
    fuente.setColor(76, 175, 80);
    fuente.setSize(40);

    Font fuente2 = new Font();
    fuente.setColor(103, 58, 183);
    fuente.setSize(20);
    .....
    .....
    .....
    Por obvias razones no muestro el codigo completo
}
```

enviarPDF

```
public void enviarPDF(){

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.googlemail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    try {
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication
            ....
            ....
    }
```

Por ultimo en mi Oncreate tengo el botón enviar para que realice la petición

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ticked_datos);
    ....
    ....
    ....
    //Y esta seria la parte mas importante de toda la pregunta...

btnConfirmarEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TicketDatos.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirmar");
            alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.check);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Hola " + Login.gNombreUsuario + " ¿Esta seguro de confirmar la orden?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Si", (dialog, id) -> {
            final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(TicketDatos.this, "Procesando...", "Espere por favor");

                //TODO: Aquí va el código para enviar el Email y generar el reporte cuando el usuario de "si" al cuadro de dialogo además de viajar a la pantalla final

                try {
                    crearPDF();
                } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                enviarPDF();

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EnviandoTicket.class);
                startActivity(i);
                loading.dismiss();
            }).setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, id) -> dialog.cancel()).create().show();
        }
    });
```

Como lo he mencionado en el comentario cuando le doy al botón confirmarEnvio se abre un Cuadro de dialogo preguntándome por ultima vez si estoy seguro de enviar el pedido ósea el PDF al momento de dar "SI" creo un progressDialog como lo han notado.
Según la gerarquia:
-Inicia el progressDialog
-Crea el PDF
-Envía el PDF
-Realiza un intent hacia la pantalla final
-Cierro el progressDialog

Y obviamente pues el progressDialog no funciona la aplicación sigue congelándose mientras se ejecutan los dos metodos

Y creo que eso seria todo espero que haya realizado la pregunta de forma correcta si no es así portavoz editarla o hacérmelo saber, además si necesitan que especifique mas código también hacérmelo saber, y pues nada espero que alguien me pueda instruir, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Es que en vez de usar `permitAll` para que no se queje, lo que deberías haber hecho es lanzar un hilo que haga ese trabajo... NUNCA, ***JAMÁS***, se hacen trabajos pesados en el *MainThread*, precisamente porque eso hace que la aplicación se quede irresponsiva... que es tu *"error"*. Tecnicamente, no es un error, lo estás haciendo tú! Mueve la generación y el envío a un thread nuevo, y desde allí puedes actualizar la interfaz y que todo vaya fluido.

Comment: Excelente eso era la solución muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos. Te invito a que publiques una respuesta tú mismo con la solución que has implementado, puesto que así ayudarás a cualquiera que tenga el mismo problema!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente, si estas realizando pruebas esto lo puedes usar, pero desactivar la politica para no permitir tareas en el hilo principal **no es recomendable en aplicaciones de producción**:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Lo que debes realizar es usar `corrutinas`, `Asynctask` o `runOnUiThread()` para realizar sin problema la operación en el hilo principal.

Por ejemplo de esta forma puedes llamar tu método  `enviarPDF()` y evitar la aplicación se "congele".

```
    final Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        
                        enviarPDF();
                        
                    }
                });
        }
    });
    workerThread.start();
```